# Can't import characters and animations from mixamo

Tags: import, .fbx, collada

I'm new to blender and I can't seem to understand where I'm going wrong with this. So I made a landscape, and wanted to import a character from mixamo. I downloaded the character with a simple animation and it comes out iether without a body and only its bone structure in Collada (.dae) , or in FBX it comes out all deformed.

collade: This is how the character looks like when imported as a .dae
[image: Text]

This is how it looks when imported as fbx:

[image: Text]

and this is how it looks when I try to rotate the fbx-imported character.

[image: Text]

It is extremely frustrating. I hope some one can help me with this. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Fbx is ok, but the mesh is controlled by its armature, so if you want to rotate it you have to rotate the armature, not the object.

Comment: yes, I realized that afterwards, thank you for your reply. However with regards to the .dae file, it simply does not import as a full character, only its bone structure is.